# Laravel query builder connection method in the constructor (L5.6)

Tags: laravel

I am working on a project where I have a set of tables having multiple prefixes (`prefix1_table1, prefix1_table2, prefix2_table1, prefix2_table2 etc`). The prefix is determined from the request parameter. In order to make the database query easier, I have written a middleware where I set the config `database.connections.mysql.prefix` to the prefix value on the fly. My intention is to use this prefix everywhere in the request lifecycle.

Now coming to the model classes, I have 2 scenarios.

**Scenario 1**

```
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager

class DbClass
{
    private $database;

    public function __construct(DatabaseManager $database)
    {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function callMe()
    {
        dd($this->database->connection('mysql::write')->getTablePrefix()); // Need the write connection
        // PRINTS PREFIX CORRECTLY
    }
}
```

**Scenario 2**

```
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager

class DbClass
{
    private $database;

    public function __construct(DatabaseManager $database)
    {
        $this->database = $database->connection('mysql::write');
        // connection() is moved to the constructor
    }

    public function callMe()
    {
        dd($this->database->getTablePrefix()); 
        // PRINTS EMPTY PREFIX
    }
}
```

What could be the reason behind getting prefix correctly in Scenario 1 and incorrectly in Scenario 2? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$database->connection('mysql::write');
```

That will store the return of the connection method to $database. I would try to move it to a method that returns an instance that can chain to getTablePrefix().

```
public function database(){
  return 'connection("mysql::write")';
}

public function callMe(){
  $this->database()->getTablePrefix();
}
```

From my experience with using a string to chain queries it's been fine, but ymmv as I haven't tested with config items.